# Improve performance of Query

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by, coalesce, sqlperformance

I have recently came across a case in which the overall SELECT statement was very fast (0.06 sec) but this part took 20 seconds:

COALESCE(T1.trees, T1.trees, T1.flowers) ASC

While used in: ORDER BY COALESCE(T2.trees, T2.trees, T2.flowers) ASC, T1.Shirts)

T1 & T2 are aliases to the same table while T2 is used for left outer Join..

Any alternatives for the COALESCE(T2.trees, T2.trees, T2.flowers) ASC part that will present better performance? 
(as I read on other posts that probably do the the fact that COALESCE(x, y) doesn't make full use of indexes). So assume that trees column is indexed.)

Cheers,
udifel

Comment: Did the select take 0.06 sec to return **some** results or **all** the results?  For example if running in SQL Developer or Toad, you will just get back the first page of results initially.   When there is no `ORDER BY` this can be very fast, but with an `ORDER BY` Oracle may have to select the entire set of results, sort them, and only then give you the first page of results.

Comment: On a sidenote: `trees`, `flowers` and `shirts` are not table column names,  but query result alias names, I guess (or rather hope :-). Correct?

Comment: @Tony Andrews: That's good thinking. Of course a result set that can be read within 0.06 secs can hardly take 20 secs to sort.